# Android Lollipop Notification Icon setColor on Cordova

Tags: java, android, cordova, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm trying to set background color for small icon color on Lollipop notification by modifying the default GCMIntentService.java from Cordova PushPlugin plugin :

> GCMIntentService.java

```
[...]

import android.os.Build;

public void createNotification(Context context, Bundle extras)
{
    [...]

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setDefaults(defaults)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setContentTitle(extras.getString("title"))
            .setTicker(extras.getString("title"))
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        mBuilder
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
            .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.main));
    } else {
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
    }

    [...]
}

[...]
```

> colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <color name="main">#009ee5</color>
</resources>
```

But, it doesn't work, the app crashes on build with the following error :

```
Error code 1 for command: ant with args: debug,-f,/Users/alex/Developpement/PhoneGap/myProject/platforms/android/build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: /Users/alex/Developpement/PhoneGap/myProject/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 8
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

If I comment "setColor" line, everything is fine (except the background color is missing), I just don't get why getColor make build fail.
I'm using SDK 21.

**EDIT :**
Updated sample code.

Comment: can you tell me how you are accessing color from resources as in my case its throwing exception cannot find symbol R.color.main

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to get this working by replacing `/libs/android-support-v13.jar` with the one from the Android SDK in `/android-sdk-macosx/extras/android/support/v13/android-support-v13.jar`

**EDIT :** I also had to replace `android-support-vX.jar` in the Facebook plugin libs folder.